# How to find the coefficient a of a $y=ax^2$ parabola?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions, conic-sections

If you have a parabola mirror with a $y=ax^2$ graph in real life, how could you calculate the coefficient $a$? The only measurement that should be performed in real life is some kind of straight line. With just these measurements, what's the best way to calculate $a$? $$$$
Edit:
About the measurement part, we can measure the height of the parabola's axis symmetry for example. Again, any straight line would just be measurable, so if we need to construct a straight line and use its measure to calculate $a$ that would answer my question.

Comment: What are the measures of the mirror?

Comment: @MichaelHoppe I see no mention of a mirror. Was there one which has now been deleted?

Comment: Your equation imposes that the parabola passes through the origin and is symmetric about the y-axis.  How this relates to your physical mirror is likely obvious to you, but Readers can't "see" what you can (a lack of context), and this makes it difficult to recommend where to put the ruler ("some kind of straight line") to take measurements.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe Any measurement that a normal person with a ruler can measure

Comment: Are you referring to a concave mirror?

Comment: With a physical parabolic mirror you should use the relation $x^2=4py$ since you can physically measure the value of $p$. Then use $a=\dfrac{1}{4p}$.

Comment: @RiverX15 Yes, a parabola mirror that is often used for concentrating light into a point.

Comment: Measure the radius $r$ and the height $h$.  From $h=ar^2$ derive that $a=h/r^2$.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe So I take any cross-section of a parabola parallel to the x-axis to get a circle and measure the height of the axis up there and the radius of that circle?

Comment: Exactly -- if it's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hold your parabolic mirror in a vertical position, with some distant object in front of it (the Sun, a tall tree with the sky as background, and so on) and a vertical white screen where to project the image. Move your mirror until the image formed on the screen is clear and detailed. Measure then the distance between the image on the screen and the center of your mirror: that is the focal distance $f$ of your screen. And $a=1/(4f)$.

Answer (score 0):

As a first qualitative step we know that if the parabola opens upward $a>0$ otherwise if it opens downward $a<0$.

For a quantitative evaluation we need at least to know the coordinates of a point $(x_0,y_0)$ on the parabola with $x_0\neq 0$ and then

$$y_0=ax_0^2 \implies a=\frac{y_0}{x_0^2}$$